# Google app script remove duplicate based on one Column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

the below code is awesome and remove the duplicates but there is one thing i want to change for example if i have column A and it contain duplicate values and column B contains unique values in this case the function don't remove the duplicates from Column A because some how it Join Column A & B together then it removes the duplicate.

what i need is to remove the duplicates based on Column A only whatever Column B is Unique Value or not

here is a sample sheet with dummy data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ViFiwoA_29oo-nz2LUK3CD7DiRqDRTW1blJRE6XHm4/edit?usp=sharing

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

- You want to remove the duplicated rows.

  - As a sample, you want to achieve as follows.
  - From

    ```
    aa  123
    bb  12345
    cc  1235
    dd  167
    aa  1234  <--- You want to delete this row
    bb  12  <--- You want to delete this row
    ff  89
    ```
  - To

    ```
    aa  123
    bb  12345
    cc  1235
    dd  167
    ff  89
    ```

If my understanding is correct, how about using `removeDuplicates()`? This method was added at July 26, 2019. I think that using this method, your script will become more simple. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script 1:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2); // Column A and B
  range.removeDuplicates([1]);
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

If your script is modified, how about the following modification?

From:

```
if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
```

To:

```
if (row[0] == newData[j][0]) {
```

#### Reference:

- [removeDuplicates(columnsToCompare)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeduplicates)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: should i delete my old script and paste this " Modified script 1 "
it's small and simple

Comment: @Mohamed Montaser Thank you for replying. The method of `removeDuplicates()` was added last month. I thought that this might be useful for your situation. So I used this for your situation. If that was useful for your situation, I'm glad.

Comment: @Mohamed Montaser Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 2):

This function removes rows where there are duplicates in column A.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dt=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var uA=[];
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<dt.length;i++) {
    if(uA.indexOf(dt[i][0])==-1) {
      uA.push(dt[i][0]);
    }else{
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be useful for someone using this function:
if you want to change the column it uses for duplicate detection; Change the 0 in those two instances of `dt[i][0]`

Comment: If they want to change it they are welcome to change it